# Stuck in Virtual Terminal and Broken Package Installer

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 22.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04, and my package installer for some reason started returning errors. I tried restarting my PC, and I've been stuck in virtual terminal ever since.

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` returns an error saying `sub process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: We need to see your complete output. `error code (1)` simply means that some subprocess failed. It's too general to offer useful advice.

Comment: @user535733, can you suggest how Umesh might provide us with more/better information?  I would but I am pretty weak on package management, sorry.